# proc import csv misreading variable names

Tags: csv, import, sas, proc

I am trying to import a csv file into sas. However I got a VAR# format name for one variable although it has got an actual name. After looking into the csv file I dint find any problem with that name(format).

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Please give us a brief code snippet and the first few lines of your CSV file.  We can help you better once we can see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured it out. The variable name was repeated which I dint even consider to check this.

Comment: Can you please look into this: when reading csv like "q1,q2,q3," . sas reads it q1,q2,q3,var4 because of the extra delimiter. So I always use the drop statement to get rid of such extra variables. Would like to know if there are any ways to overcome this while importing

Comment: Think you're gonna have to either remove the extra delimiters before importing or use a (drop = var:) statement to drop all imported variables beginning with the letters "var"

Comment: @superfluous drop=var: worked great. Thanks.

Comment: You can also just not use PROC IMPORT and instead write your own data step to read the CSV file.  I usually find that it is faster, clearer and prevents these types of issues.